# Can I lay a flash object on top of another flash object?

Tags: jquery, html, flash, actionscript, adobe

I was wondering if I could lay a video of a person's camera on top of a youtube video?  Right now the YouTube video is laying on top of my camera every time.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var params = {wmode:"transparent", bgcolor:"#0fb5df"};
        swfobject.embedSWF("camera.swf", "camera", "460", "385", "10.0","expressInstall.swf",,params);
    </script>

<div class="frame-holder" style="position;relative; z-index:0; ">
                                <div id="camera"  style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; z-index:500;  ">
                                </div>
                                <div   style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; z-index:300;">
                                    <iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/test&wmode=transparent" allowfullscreen frameborder="0">
</iframe>



                            </div>
```

Comment: I'd suggest trying to give a higher `z-index` value to your camera element, or a negative `z-index` value (instead of 0) to your `iframe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wmode=transparent is not passed correctly to the youtube url, use:

http://www.youtube.com/embed/test?wmode=transparent

Explanation: '?' is the separator between the url and the list of parameters, '&' is used to separate the parameters, like this: http://www.test.com/test.php?param1=value1&param2=value2

Update:

You indicated that the '&' was a typo, I did some more research and found your issue.

The problem you are facing is that the style attribute of the template div gets replaced by the style of the swfobject.embedSWF() call. (as the whole div gets removed and replaced by a new object tag)

So add for example:

```
var attributes = {style: "z-index: 500; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0"};
```

and change your call to:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("demo.swf", "camera", "460", "385", "10.0", "expressInstall.swf", {}, params, attributes);
```

This way the style attribute -- including the z-index -- will be set correctly on the object tag.

Another solution might be to wrap an extra div around the container div and set your style attribute there.

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo.  Still didn't do anything.

Comment: The update did the trick. Thanks for letting me know. I couldn't find anything on the internet.